# FB.XFBML.parse does not reparse FB widgets

Tags: parsing, facebook-like, xfbml

I have a function call back on `auth.login` and would like to reparse my `fb:like` elements. Other actions are performed during the `auth.login` callback, and they execute just fine, but the `.parse` does not! I try executing `FB.XFBML.parse();` in the console and it shows `undefined` and then after three seconds a console message saying `2 XFBML tags failed to render in 30000ms.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who happens to run across this question running into the same problem I did...

Basically what I wanted to do was after a user logged into my website, I wanted to refresh the 'Like' button iFrame to reflect such. `FB.XFBML.parse();` was only resulting in errors...so I thought "Maybe I'll just refresh the iFrame?" and since I am using jQuery as my framework - I figured I'd stick with it.

So, here's what I ended up doing:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    if(response.status == 'connected') {
        $("#login_fb").hide(); // was already doing this part
        $('#like_fb > span > iframe').attr('src', function(i,val) { return val; }); // this is what I wanted to refresh
        //FB.XFBML.parse(); -- THIS WAS GENERATING AN ERROR
    }
});
```

Hopefully this will help someone else!